# Time intervals in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to plot time intervals for my data. Basically I want to compare recording of 2 systems for different individuals. The code might be a bit inefficient.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

df.system1.person1<-data.frame(
time.start.person1=c("12:12:30","12:13:10","12:13:50"),
time.end.person1=c("12:12:35","12:13:20","12:13:55")
)

df.system2.person1=data.frame(
time.start.person1=c("12:12:30","12:13:50"),
time.end.person1=c("12:13:25","12:14:00")
)
df.system1.person2=data.frame(
time.start.person2=c("12:12:30","12:13:10","12:13:50"),
time.end.person2=c("12:12:35","12:13:20","12:13:55")
)

df.system2.person2=data.frame(
time.start.person2=c("12:12:30","12:13:50"),
time.end.person2=c("12:13:25","12:14:00")
)

ndf.system1.person1 <- melt(df.system1.person1, measure.vars = c("time.start.person1",          "time.end.person1"))
ndf.system2.person1 <- melt(df.system2.person1, measure.vars = c("time.start.person1", "time.end.person1"))
ndf.system1.person2 <- melt(df.system1.person2, measure.vars = c("time.start.person2", "time.end.person2"))
ndf.system2.person2 <- melt(df.system2.person2, measure.vars = c("time.start.person2", "time.end.person2"))


ndf.system1.person1$value2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(ndf.system1.person1$value, "%H:%M:%S"))
ndf.system2.person1$value2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(ndf.system2.person1$value, "%H:%M:%S"))
ndf.system1.person2$value2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(ndf.system1.person2$value, "%H:%M:%S"))
ndf.system2.person2$value2<-as.POSIXct(strptime(ndf.system2.person2$value, "%H:%M:%S"))

data=rbind(ndf.system1.person1,ndf.system2.person1,ndf.system1.person2,ndf.system2.person2)
data$Arg[1:6]="System1"
data$Arg[7:10]="System2"
data$Arg[11:16]="System1"
data$Arg[17:20]="System2"

data$Ind[1:10]="Person 1"
data$Ind[11:20]="Person 2"

ggplot(data,aes(x=value2,y=Arg))+geom_line(size=1)+ facet_grid(.~Ind,scales="free_x",space="free_x")+xlab("") + ylab("") +theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none",axis.text=element_text(size=14),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=+1),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

However, instead of time intervals I get one solid line. The time intervals should be start.time-end.time. Also, on the x axis I would like to get HH:MM format. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a picture or example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you combine your data does not seem to be suitable for the plot you want to make. Below you find a different approach to combine the data that you originally created. Then you can use `geom_linerange` to make your plot.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(cbind(df.system1.person1, Arg = "System1", Ind = "Person 1"), 
                                 cbind(df.system2.person1, Arg = "System2", Ind = "Person 1"),
                                 cbind(df.system1.person2, Arg = "System1", Ind = "Person 2"),
                                 cbind(df.system2.person2, Arg = "System2", Ind = "Person 2")), 
                            'colnames<-', c('start.time', 'end.time', 'Arg', 'Ind')))
#
ggplot(df, aes(x = Arg, ymin = start.time, ymax=end.time)) + 
  geom_linerange(size = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(.~Ind,scales="free_y",space="free_y") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, vjust=0.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

EDIT: In order to change the time format, you need to first convert the times to `POSIXct` format and then use `scale_y_datetime`.

```
# change formats
df$start.time <- as.POSIXct(df$start.time, format='%H:%M:%S')
df$end.time <- as.POSIXct(df$end.time, format='%H:%M:%S')
# load additional package
require(scales)
# added scale_y_datetime. 
# The example data you provide span less than 2 minutes, 
# so I used the date format with seconds and 30 second breaks
# You need to change this to get 15 minute breaks and no seconds. 
ggplot(df, aes(x = Arg, ymin = start.time, ymax=end.time)) + 
  geom_linerange(size = 1) +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("30 secs"),    # change to "15 mins"
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M:%S")) + # change to "%H:%M"
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(.~Ind,scales="free_y",space="free_y") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, vjust=0.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. Is there a way to change y-axis format to HH:MM with regular intervals of 15 minutes from the start time until the end time?